# How to combine queries in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have data that arrives as so in a sheet from a google form. It's to manage pieces of our product that we send to a painter.

```
in/out  model_1   model_2
-------------------------
in        10         0
out        5         0
in        10        10
in         2         5
out        2        12
```

I want something like so

```
model          IN    OUT
-------------------------
model_1        22     7
model_2        15    12
```

I managed to get the first column with a query with something along those lines

```
SELECT SUM(B), SUM(C) WHERE A="in"
```

Then I added a `TRANSPOSE`.

How to add to the query a second column `where A="out"` ?

This is the real query :

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Réponses au formulaire 2'!A1:W; "SELECT SUM(E), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K), SUM(L), SUM(M), SUM(N), SUM(O), SUM(P), SUM(Q), SUM(R), SUM(S), SUM(T), SUM(U), SUM(V), SUM(W) WHERE D = 'DEPOT'";1))
```

Hope you understand what I mean. Maybe another approach is best?

But for now I'm kinda stuck but not really happy with my solution of adding a second query as it add a column of labels sum_a sum_b....

Answer (score 0):

Would this do it?

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY('Réponses au formulaire 2'!A1:W; "SELECT D,SUM(E), SUM(F), SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K), SUM(L), SUM(M), SUM(N), SUM(O), SUM(P), SUM(Q), SUM(R), SUM(S), SUM(T), SUM(U), SUM(V), SUM(W) WHERE D = 'DEPOT' OR D = '2nd Option' group by D";1))
```

Change *2nd Option* with your desired value

Comment: This was the first answer that worked. I learned that the OR selection gave me a new row wich is cool. BUT entering all the SUMs all through the alphabet is... Not optimal. I'll keep this solution in mind for smaller datasets. But the second answer though harder to get working with my locals really does the hard work for you ! Thank for the answer anyway ;)

Comment: I was just adapting what you already had written, obviously there were other options ;)

Comment: No worries ! It saved my day! Even if at the end of the day I realised my starting proposition was sub optimal XD

Answer (score 0):

you could try this formula:

`=transpose({{B1:G1};BYCOL(FILTER(B2:G,A2:A="in"),lambda(row,sum(row)));BYCOL(FILTER(B2:G,A2:A="out"),lambda(row,sum(row)))})`

[image]

Comment: I need to edit it to fit my dataset but it looks like what i am looking for . Thanks.

Comment: I had a rough time adapting it to my french no coma setting. I managed to get each BYCOL to work But when i add them in the array litteral they don't sum the data anymore ? Kinda weird `=transpose({{'Réponses au formulaire 2'!E1:W};BYCOL(FILTER('Réponses au formulaire 2'!E1:W;'Réponses au formulaire 2'!D1:D="DEPOT");lambda(column; SOMME(column)));BYCOL(FILTER('Réponses au formulaire 2'!E1:W;'Réponses au formulaire 2'!D1:D="RETRAIT");lambda(column; SOMME(column)))})`

Comment: Got it ! The first array in the array litteral got in the way, it was spilling all the table not just the mane of the producsts. I edited it to be a single row and its now a single column when transposed, and it works as expected.

Comment: awesome.. cool then:)